# R, how to convert a 1*1 data frame to an character vector

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have a data.frame (a):

```
 str(a)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ HN:'data.frame':     1 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ HN: Factor w/ 1 level "FORT": 1
```

I want to convert it into character vector. How Can we do it.

Comment: In R, data.frames are actually lists of same length. What you have here is a data.frame, that has a list called HN, and that list has another lits called HN. Something funky is going on when you're creating this object, I would look there.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
as.character(a[,1])
```

or simply:

```
as.character(a[,])
```

If you mean splitting into separate letter you can do it using strsplit:

```
strsplit(x=as.character(a[,]), '')
```

Comment: Could you please delete you answer. Actually due to my poor question, I got many negative votes, and it is blocking me in many things in stackoverflow. (note: I can only delete qns, when there is no answer.) Thanks in Advance

Comment: I could do it but as far as I know it won't help you much. You can get reputation back, but it won't make your account clean. I would recommend if you improve this question (explain how you get there and was the exact problem) and I can nominate it for reopening,